# save each sheet on its original name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code stated below in which i am saving sheet wise file in prn

i do not want to give name to the file when it save ,i just want to save my each sheet by its original name (so , the the sheet name raj,taj,bazz. they all save by its original name.

```
Sub CONVERT()
    Dim vcounter As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Activate

        vcounter = 2
        While Range("A" & vcounter).Value <> ""
            Range("a" & vcounter).Value = Range("a" & vcounter).Value + 1
            vcounter = vcounter + 1
        Wend

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\apache.prn"
     Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\apache.prn"` Change it to (Untested) `ws.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\" & ws.Name & ".prn"`

Answer (score 1):

This code is **tested** and it save a file with the `ActiveSheet` name and with the same extension:

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\" & ActiveSheet.Name
```

If you need to save it with another extension, use this code instead:

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".prn"
```

---

In your code, if you need to save each sheet with its name, just change `ActiveSheet` with your `ws` variable, like this:

```
Sub CONVERT()
    Dim vcounter As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Activate

        vcounter = 2
        While Range("A" & vcounter).Value <> ""
            Range("a" & vcounter).Value = Range("a" & vcounter).Value + 1
            vcounter = vcounter + 1
        Wend

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\" & ws.Name & ".prn"
     Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: @RISHABH SINGH You're welcome. If this answer was helpful, please accept it so others can benefit from it. :)